# Ubuntu rebooted in emergency mode. How to solve the errors indicated without fresh install?

Tags: kernel, systemd, docker, reboot, fsck

After running a heavy docker container, docker stopped responding (15+ minutes for any command, even `docker ps -a`).
So after shutting down everything and checking no one else is logged in, I rebooted the system (workstation with Ubuntu 22.04).

The reboot did not succeed and the system entered emergency mode. With `journalctl -b -p err` command, I could see the following errors:

```
kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
systemd-fstab-generator[626]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/softs.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
systemd-fstab-generator[626]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/softs.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
systemd[614]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
systemd-fsck[1152]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
systemd[1] Failed to start file system check on /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-</DEV/SDA1 UUID>
```

In USB live mode, I could access my `/home` and created a backup. What I was wondering is if its possible to fix these issues without a fresh ubuntu install?

I feel it should be possible. Just a Docker container shouldn't have caused much trouble.

Kindly help.